# Menu hamburguesa. No se despliega

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con una web y no sé por que no se despliega el menú hamburguesa. Supongo que falta algo de código. Soy principiante, si alguien me hecha un mano, se lo agradecería. https://dronnavarra.es/ Esta es la web, como podeís ver no se despliega. Si me explicais que necesitais de forma concisa, intentaré facilitar. grcias

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="pre-head">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_address_text' ) ): ?>
                            <span class="head-text-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_address_url' ) ): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'header_address_url' ) ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'header_address_text' ) ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'header_address_text' ) ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </span>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_telephone_text' ) ): ?>
                            <span class="head-text-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_telephone_url' ) ): ?>
                                    <a href="tel:<?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'header_telephone_url' ) ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'header_telephone_text' ) ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'header_telephone_text' ) ); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_socials', 1 ) ) {
                            get_template_part( 'part-social-icons' );
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mast-head">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="mast-head-wrap">
                            <div class="mast-head-left">
                                <?php if ( is_front_page() ): ?>
                                    <h1 class="site-logo">
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="site-logo">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
                                        the_custom_logo();
                                    } ?>

                                    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'show_site_title', 1 ) ): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="site-logo-textual">
                                            <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ( is_front_page() ): ?>
                                    </h1>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    </p>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'show_site_tagline', 1 ) ): ?>
                                    <p class="site-tagline"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mast-head-right">
                                <nav class="nav">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
                                        'container'      => '',
                                        'menu_id'        => '',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'navigation'
                                    ) ); ?>
                                </nav>
                                <div id="mobilemenu"></div><a href="#mobilemenu" class="mobile-menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'mobile-menu-trigger', 'technico' ); ?></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que corrijas tu pregunta y podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Lo siento, no sé que poner o buscar para que me podaís ayudar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. La función `<?php wp_head(); ?>` sirve para colocar allí la cabecera de tu proyecto, allí deberías estar declarando el head y el header, ya que esta es una buena practica de wordpress.
2. Acabo de correr tu codigo sobre una plantilla propia de wordpress y pude visualizar lo que esta sucediendo, tu menú no se esta desplegando por:

2.1:

```
                  <div class="mast-head-right">
                                <nav class="nav">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
                                        'container'      => '',
                                        'menu_id'        => '',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'navigation'
                                    ) ); ?>
                                </nav>
                                <div id="mobilemenu"></div><a href="#mobilemenu" class="mobile-menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'mobile-menu-trigger', 'technico' ); ?></span></a>
                            </div>
```

Este código es el encargado del menú la vista inferior para resoluciones 991px el menú desktop se oculta con la linea de código css:

```
@media (max-width: 991px)
header nav > div {
    display: none;
}
```

Si te das cuenta el menú que se hace visible es el:

```
<div id="mobilemenu"></div>
```

Que de hecho lo tiene vació, aqui dentro deberías tener nuevamente tu menú con personalización CSS, y luego mediante javaScript o JQuery deberías estar colocando las acciones o mas sencillo lee la [documentación oficial de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#external-content).

```
<div id="mobilemenu">
                                 <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                            'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
                                            'container'      => '',
                                            'menu_id'        => '',
                                            'menu_class'     => 'navigation'
                                        ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Quedando mas o menos así, cabe destacar que esto es solo un ejemplo hecho con apuro...

Comment: Responder con únicamente enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Más que una solución a la pregunta, tu respuesta parece un comentario. Por favor revisa: [¿Cómo responder correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Adicional, las respuestas cuya solución son un enlace externo se consideran de baja calidad, por favor agrega en tu respuesta la información más relevante de dicho enlace

Comment: Adicional 2: El enlace que has puesto no resuelve la pregunta, ni siquiera es la documentación oficial de Bootstrap sino un tema basado en él.